# Shiny : R: wilcox.test : change "value" -Output

Tags: r, shiny, statistics

I am working on a tiny shiny app, that allows the user to upload some data and run some statistics on it. I now have two things I would like to change in the output. [image: This is the output at the moment]
However, as you can see, the data part is quite saying nothing, I rather have the output: data: Group1 and Group2
I also would like to have `n` as the number of subjects(here: 109,114,115).

This is the code to produce the current output:

```
statsPaired <- function(boolean_dt1, boolean_dt2){
  for (i in 4: (length(boolean_dt1))){
    print(wilcox.test( (unlist(boolean_dt1[,i, with = FALSE])), unlist(boolean_dt2[,i, with = FALSE]) , paired = T, exact= FALSE))
    cat("\n")
  }
}
```

Comment: The output mimics what you put in. Either rename the values of the arguments or create your own version of the output based on the contents of the returned object

Comment: thanks.  I am not quite sure how to create my own version of the output.

Comment: Look at `str(wilcox.test( (unlist(boolean_dt1[,i, with = FALSE])), unlist(boolean_dt2[,i, with = FALSE]) , paired = T, exact= FALSE))` to see which elements it contains